# Struggling to describe JPA or Hibernate relationship using annotations

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Following is simplified version of schema to describe the actual problem.

Consider following three classes. MetaDataInfo stores current versions about various meta data tables. Column "isCurrent" points to currently active version.

```
@Entity
class MetaDataInfo
{
   @Column
   int version;
   @Column
   String type;
   @Column
   boolean isCurrent;
}

@Entity
VersionedInfo {
  @Column
  int version;
}

@Entity
Data {

  VersionedInfo info;
}
```

Is it possible to ask hibernate using annotations auto provide the VersionedInfo from data table when Data is read from database - like it does for other relationships. From SQL perspective query will look something like follows

```
select * from VersionedInfo where version = (select version from MetaDataInfo where isCurrent = true and type = "VersionedInfo")
```

Comment: How about annotate your VersionInfo as well? Also I don't understand really what you're trying to do here. Seems like you are misusing Hibernate here. For me it seems like these MetaData and Version classes are common abstract classes.

Comment: You can use [Hibernate filters](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-data-filter-example-xml-and-annotation/) to achieve this functionality, create a filter with your where, and activate it before the queries. (This is not JPA compliant)

Comment: @Vaelyr - Did not understand your question. If you are asking annotating Data.info entry, this is my question. What annotation should I use here. I want to get to an object which has particular where clause and its not straight relationship as current version comes from different table.

Comment: @ArturoVolpe, this looks promising. I'll try it out. Thanks.

Comment: Also, if you want a ready to production solution to your "audit" methods, check [Envers](http://envers.jboss.org/) it's from jboss, and don't need a complex configuration

Comment: @ArturoVolpe, this works. If you want can you pleas post this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Hibernate filters](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-data-filter-example-xml-and-annotation/) to achieve this functionality, create a filter with your where, and activate it before the queries. (This is not JPA compliant)

Like this:

```
@Entity
class MetaDataInfo
{
   @Column
   int version;
   @Column
   String type;
   @Column
   boolean isCurrent;
}

@Entity
@FilterDef(name="lastInfo")
VersionedInfo {
  @Column
  @Filter(name="lastInfo", condition="(version = (select version from MetaDataInfo where isCurrent = true and type = \"VersionedInfo\")"
  int version;
}

@Entity
Data {

  VersionedInfo info;
}
```

And the usage:

```
session.enableFilter("lastInfo")
// queries
session.disableFilter("lastInfo")
```